# How to list all image files in Flask static subdirectory?

Tags: python, flask

```
def get_path():
    imgs = []

    for img in os.listdir('/Users/MYUSERNAME/Desktop/app/static/imgs/'):
        imgs.append(img)
    image = random.randint(0, len(imgs)-1) #gen random image path from images in directory
    return imgs[image].split(".")[0] #get filename without extension

@app.route("/blahblah")
def show_blah():
    img = get_path()
    return render_template('blahblah.html', img=img) #template just shows image
```

What I want to do is not have to get the files using os unless there is a way to do it using flask methods. I know this way will only work with my computer and not any server I try and upload it on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Flask app has a property `static_folder` that returns the absolute path to the static folder.  You can use this to know what directory to list without tying it to your computer's specific folder structure.  To generate a url for the image to be used in an HTML `<img/>` tag, use `url_for('static', filename='static_relative_path_to/file')'.

```
import os
from random import choice
from flask import url_for, render_template


@app.route('/random_image')
def random_image():
    names = os.listdir(os.path.join(app.static_folder, 'imgs'))
    img_url = url_for('static', filename=os.path.join('imgs', choice(names)))

    return render_template('random_image.html', img_url=img_url)
```